# How to safely convert unsigned value to signed?

Tags: c++, c

As I read, in signed arithmetic there are many cases of undefined behaviour. Thus, I prefer to calculate results (even signed ones) using unsigned arithmetic, which is specified without undefined cases.

However, when the result is obtained using unsigned arithmetic, the last step, the conversion to the signed value remains to be done.

Here is a code I wrote and my question is if the code works in accordance with the rules, i.e., whether it is safe, not relying on some undefined/unspecified behaviour?

```
/*
    function to safely convert given unsigned value
    to signed result having the required sign
        sign == 1 means the result shall be negative,
        sign == 0 means the result shall be nonnegative
    returns 1 on success, 0 on failure
*/
int safe_convert(unsigned value, int sign, int *result) {
    if (sign) {
        if (value > -(unsigned)INT_MIN) return 0; // value too big
        if (!value) return 0; // cannot convert zero to negative int
        *result = INT_MIN + (int)((-(unsigned)INT_MIN) - value);
    } else {
        if (value > (unsigned)INT_MAX) return 0; //value too big
        *result = (int)value;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Eventually, is there a way that is simpler, not relying on undefined/unspecified behaviour and doing the same thing?

Comment: Your function returns without writing anything into `*result` in at least one case....

Comment: I have problems with `-(unsigned)INT_MIN`. `INT_MIN` is already negative, you then cast this as an unsigned, and then you then make this negative. So the expression does in fact nothing.

Comment: You're worried about undefined behavior? What behavior are you trying to avoid, and how does this "solve" that "problem" ? You're touting around your own "sign-bit" and all you have to show for it is one extra bit of representation and the headache of managing this thing. *What problem are you **really** trying to solve?* ?

Comment: "Your function returns without writing anything into *result in at least one case." - yes, sure, that is intended and signaled by the return value in case the result does not fit.

Comment: "I have problems with `-(unsigned)INT_MIN`. `INT_MIN` is already negative, you then cast this as an unsigned, and then you then make this negative. So the expression does in fact nothing." Wrong. `INT_MIN` is an `int` value. `(unsigned)INT_MIN` is an `unsigned` value. `-(unsigned)INT_MIN` is an unsigned value too, just not necessarily equal to `(unsigned)INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only value that could be problematic is `INT_MIN`. Therefore I would just do something like

```
int safe_convert(unsigned value, int sign, int *result) {
    if (sign) {
        if (value > -(unsigned)INT_MIN) return 0;           // value too big
        if (-(unsigned)INT_MIN > (unsigned)INT_MAX          // compile constant
             &&
             value == -(unsigned)INT_MIN)                   // special case       
           *result = INT_MIN;
        else *result = -(int)value;
    } else {
        if (value > (unsigned)INT_MAX) return 0; //value too big
        *result = (int)value;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I don't think that the case of asking for a negative zero justifies an error return.

Comment: You are right about the negative zero, error return in that case looks unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

**Eventually, is there a way that is simpler, not relying on undefined behaviour and doing the same thing?**

```
short x = (short) value;

int y = (int) value;
```

But be sure on what integral type you are casting to. `value` may go out of the range of the signed type used.

Comment: Not undefined, true, but implementation defined if `value` is outside the range of the signed type in question.

Comment: Of course the value may go out of range of the signed type used. I am aware of that, hence my above question. Using an unsafe code like this and being warned about the fact it is actually unsafe does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion from unsigned to signed is not undefined, but implementation defined. From C++ Standard, chapter 4.7 Integral conversions, paragraph 3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and
>   bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined

Therefore the following is implementation defined and on many platforms exactly what you may expect (wrap around):

```
unsigned u = -1;
int i = (int)u;
```

Comment: You sure you didn't mean `UINT_MAX` rather than (-1) ?

Comment: Conversion from signed to unsigned is well defined. This will always result in the largest unsigned value.

Comment: Since by 6.3.1.3 (C99) this will add (UINT_MAX+1) to bring the value in-range, you're most-certainly correct, I just wasn't sure if that was the motivation behind it.

Answer (score 1):

The condition when `sign` is false (a positive number) is all ready well handled, it is when `sign` is true (a negative number) is tricky.  So rather than:

```
if (value > -(unsigned)INT_MIN) return 0; // value too big
*result = INT_MIN + (int)((-(unsigned)INT_MIN) - value);
```

suggest

```
// 1st half is for 2's compliment machines
// 2nd half is for symmetric ints like 1's compliment and signed ints
// Optimization will simplify the real code to 1 compare
if ((((INT_MIN + 1) == -INT_MAX) && (value > ((unsigned)INT_MAX + 1u))) ||
    (( INT_MIN      == -INT_MAX) && (value >  (unsigned)INT_MAX      ))) return 0;
int i = (int) value;
*result = -i;
```

The `INT_MIN == -INT_MAX` tests could be used to conditionally allow a signed zero.